# xamarin.forms ImageSource set from code sometimes disappears, doesnt work on iOS at all

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I have this xaml class:

```
<ContentView
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    HeightRequest="130"
    WidthRequest="90"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="InteriorCircle.Pages.MainMenu.CV_PinStyle">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Frame
                HeightRequest="130"
                WidthRequest="90"
                VerticalOptions="Start"
                HasShadow="False"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                BackgroundColor="#565656"
                Padding="0"
                CornerRadius="25"
                IsClippedToBounds="true">
                <StackLayout Padding="5">
                    <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Image x:Name="img_pic"
                               Margin="3,0,0,0"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center">
                           <Image.Clip>
                               <EllipseGeometry
                                   Center="27,27"
                                   RadiusX="27"
                                   RadiusY="27"/>
                           </Image.Clip>
                        </Image>
                        <Ellipse Stroke="#60CED3"
                                 StrokeThickness="6"
                                 WidthRequest="60"
                                 HeightRequest="60"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Label
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        x:Name="label_title"
                        TextColor="White"
                        LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                        FontFamily="JakartaReg"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                        FontSize="12"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label
                        x:Name="label_price"
                        TextColor="White"
                        FontFamily="JakartaBold"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                        FontSize="10"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

I retrieve content from another class (event) and set it to the properties from here:

```
 private async Task SetContent(EventType events)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            byte[] bt = Converters.StringToByteArray(events.eventPictureThumb);


            label_title.Text = events.name;
            label_price.Text = Converters.GetDecimalPriceFromCents(events.priceInCents) + " €";

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var source = Converters.ReturnImageSourceFromString(Converters.ByteArrayToString(bt));
                img_pic.Source = source;
            });


        }
```

However, this does not work sometimes on Android, on iOS not at all.

When I set an image directly in xaml, it is always displayed. On iOS, when the image comes from code, it is never displayed. On Android, it is displayed most of the times, but fails sometimes. When multiple objects load into the view the old ones lose their images.

I am adding the view like so:

```
    var startPin = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromView(new CV_PinStyle(currentEvent));

    Pin pin = new Pin
    {
        Label = currentEvent.name,             
        Tag = currentEvent.tblEventID+Constants.DELIMITER+currentEvent.userID,
        Icon = startPin,
        Type = PinType.Place,
        Position = position
    };


    gMap?.Pins?.Add(pin);
```

So I am doing somethign wrong here,

can you help me?

Comment: Did you try to debug the code and see if the source is null when the image disappear?

Comment: Yeah ofc. The source is never null.

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .